Does there exist a complex matrix $A$ with shape $n\times n$ such that $\operatorname{Tr}(A^k)=k$ for all natural $k$?
$\quad$ Does there exist a complex matrix $A$ with shape $n\times n$ such that $\operatorname{Tr}(A^k)=k$ for all natural $k$?
$\quad$ I solve this problem using charasteristic polynomial of $A$ and prove that the all eigenvalues of $A$ is $1$ then $\operatorname{Tr}(A^k)=n$ so that there is not exist matrix with such properties.
$\quad$ I am haunted by the thought that there is a shorter and more elegant solution. If you find or have a more elegant and short solution, please show me.
$\quad\chi_A(t)=\det(tI-A)=t^n-c_{n-1}t^{n-1}-\ldots-c_1t-c_0\Rightarrow \chi_A(A)=0\Rightarrow$
$$
A^n=c_{n-1}A^{n-1}+\ldots+c_1A+c_0I\Rightarrow
$$
$$
A^{n+k}=c_{n-1}A^{n+k-1}+\ldots+c_1A^{k+1}+c_0A^k\Rightarrow
$$
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(A^{n+k})=c_{n-1}\operatorname{Tr}(A^{n+k-1})+\ldots+c_1\operatorname{Tr}(A^{k+1})+c_0\operatorname{Tr}(A^k)\Rightarrow
$$
$$
n+k=c_{n-1}(n+k-1)+\ldots+c_1(k+1)+c_0k\Rightarrow
$$
$$
c_{n-1}+\ldots+c_0=1\Rightarrow \chi_A(1)=0\Rightarrow
$$
$$
A\sim\begin{bmatrix}
1 & u\\
0 & B
\end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow
$$
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(B^k)=k-1
$$
$$
\ldots
$$
All eigenvalues of $A$ is equal to $1$

There is probably get a short, elegant solution which applies the Jordan normal form of the matrix, but you might regard that as cheating: all the hard work regarding eigenvalues is just hidden in the proof of the existence of Jordan normal form. Perhaps you should clarify what you mean by "shorter and more elegant".

I think about Jordan normal form and I got that $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$ it's true that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i^k=k$ but I cannot prove that system of equations has no solution.

Perhaps also you should edit your proof to explain how you actually proved this. Without that, we are left wondering: Shorter and more elegant than what?

Let $B = (A - A^2)$ then $B^n$ has trace $0$ for all $n \geq 2$.
To see this let
$(x - x^2)^n = a_nx^n + \dots + a_{2n}x^{2n}$
then trace of $B^n$ $=$ $na_n + \ldots + 2na_{2n}$
Note that RHS is just derivative of $(x - x^2)^n$ evaluated at $x = 1$, which is a root of multiplicity $>$ $1$ whenever $n > 1$ hence the derivative $0$.
In particular if $C = B^2$ then $C$ and all its powers have trace $0$ $\implies$ $C$ is nilpotent $\implies$ $B$ is nilpotent $\implies$ $A$ and $A^2$ have equal trace which is a contradiction.

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}$$
Work over any $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra, not just $\mathbb{C}$. The assumption can be organized into the formal power series
$$\Tr\frac{A}{1-tA}=\frac{1}{(1-t)^2}\text{.}$$
Formally integrating and exponentiating using Newton's identities or the Jacobi formula gives
$$\det(1-tA)^{-1} = \exp\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)\text{,}$$
i.e.,
$$\det(1+tA) = \exp\left(\frac{t}{1+t}\right)\text{.}$$
The left side terminates in degree $n$, but the right doesn't—a contradiction. (In a different generality, if $A$ is a trace-class operator on a separable Hilbert space, $\det(1+tA)$ is holomorphic in $t$, so we still have a contradiction.)

Note that any non-real eigenvalues must come in conjugate pairs (all traces are $\in \mathbb R$ so Newton's Identities imply a characteristic polynomial  $\in\mathbb R[x]$).  Now consider the Hankel matrix $H_A$ whose component $i,j$ equals $\text{trace}\big(A^{i+j-1}\big)$ $\big[\text{ref}$ $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z},\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^k=(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i)^k$ implies at most one number of $\{\lambda_i\}$ doesn't equal $0$? $\big]$
$\text{rank}(H_A)=2$ since its $j$th column is equal to the first column + $(j-1)\cdot\mathbf 1$ $\implies A$ has exactly $2$ distinct non-zero eigenvalues per the link.
The leading $2\times 2$ principal submatrix has determinant $1\cdot 3 - 2\cdot 2=-1$ so $H_A=V^T DV\not \succeq \mathbf 0\implies A$ has a non-real eigenvalue (consider the leading $2\times 2$ principal minor of $H_{A^2}$ to rule out $A$ having a negative and positive eigenvalue) $\implies$ $A$ has $\lambda$ and $\overline \lambda$ each with multiplicity $m$.  Thus the original post reads $2m\cdot\text{Re}\big(\lambda^k\big)= m\cdot \lambda^k + m\cdot(\overline \lambda)^k =\text{trace}\big(A^k)=k$ for all $k\in \mathbb N\implies \lambda \in \mathbb R$ since $\lambda^k$ is in the right half plane for all $k$; thus $\lambda$ is both real and non-real and that is a contradiction.

sketch of a different approach:
For any $\mathbb F$ where $\text{char }\mathbb F = 0$ (or for positive characteristic we impose the usual restriction of $\text{char }\mathbb F \gt n$)
if such an $A$ exists then there must be some minimal $n$ (obviously $n\geq 2$) where $A$ exists. So we focus on this minimal case; this implies $A$ is invertible.  Now compute the same thing two  different ways:
(i.) $\text{rank}\big(H_A\big)=2$ as above so $A$ has exactly 2 unique non-zero eigenvalues
[technically we work over a splitting field whenever eigenvalues are mentioned]
(ii.) consider the Hankel matrix whose component $i,j$ equals $\text{trace}\big(A^{i+j-2}\big)$, i.e. the one here: If $A$ has distinct eigenvalues, then all matrices close enough to $A$ also have distinct eigenvalues .  If $n\geq 3$ then we can check that the leading $3\times 3$ principal submatrix has determinant $-n\neq 0$ hence that matrix has rank (at least) $3$ hence $A$ has (at least) $3$ unique eigenvalues, all of which are non-zero which contradicts (i.). Conclude: $n=2$.
$ \begin{pmatrix}
2  & 1  & 2   \\ 
1  & 2 & 3   \\ 
2 &  3& 4  \\ 
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
\text{trace}\big(I_2\big)  & \text{trace}\big(A^1\big)  & \text{trace}\big(A^2\big)   \\ 
\text{trace}\big(A^1\big)  & \text{trace}\big(A^2\big)  & \text{trace}\big(A^3\big)   \\ 
\text{trace}\big(A^2\big) &  \text{trace}\big(A^3\big)& \text{trace}\big(A^4\big)  \\ 
\end{pmatrix}= V^T V$
where $V$ is $2\times 3$ but the matrix on the left has determinant $=-2$
$\implies 3=\text{rank}\begin{pmatrix}
2  & 1  & 2   \\ 
1  & 2 & 3   \\ 
2 &  3& 3  \\ 
\end{pmatrix}  =\text{rank}\big(V^T V\big)\leq \text{rank}\big( V^T\big)\leq 2$
which is a contradiction
alternative finish after (ii.)
Checking $A$'s first two traces implies the  Companion Matrix $\left[\begin{matrix}0 & \frac{1}{2}\\1 & 1\end{matrix}\right]$ generates the OP's traces, but
$\text{trace}\left(\left[\begin{matrix}0 & \frac{1}{2}\\1 & 1\end{matrix}\right]^3\right) =\frac{5}{2}\neq 3$

Complex Analysis Proof:
Let $A$ have characteristic polynomial $p(z)$ and spectral radius $R\geq 1$ since $\text{trace}\big(A^k\big)$ is bounded away from $0$.   Then in the annulus $\big\{z: R \lt \vert z\vert\lt \infty\big\}$ the rational function $r(z) = \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{z-\lambda_k}$, has Laurent Series
$ = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \text{trace}\big(A^{k-1}\big)\cdot z^{-k}= n z^{-1} + \sum_{k=2}^\infty (k-1)\cdot z^{-k}$
(check Cauchy's Integral Formula and the fact that $r\big(\infty\big)=0$)
This implies we have analytic $f: \big(0, R^{-1}\big)\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ given by
$f(z) = r\big(z^{-1}\big)  = z\cdot\big(n + \sum_{k=2}^\infty (k-1)\cdot z^{k-1}\big)= n\cdot z + z^2\cdot \frac{d}{dz}\Big(\frac{1}{1-z}\Big)$
where $0$ is a removable singularity that we've defined over.  $f$ has a pole at some $\vert z\vert =R^{-1}$ but it inherits a radius of convergence of $1$ from $\frac{1}{1-z}\implies R^{-1}\geq 1\implies R^{-1}=1=R$.
$\text{Triangle inequality }\implies  n\geq \Big\vert\text{trace}\big(A^{n+1}\big)\Big\vert=n+1$ and that is a contradiction
Takeaway:
The underlying problem for the OP is that $\big\vert\text{trace}\big(A^k\big)\big\vert\to \infty$ but it does so too slowly allowing $f$ to be analytic in $B\big(0,1\big)$.   In particular $\big\vert\text{trace}\big(A^k\big)\big\vert\to \infty\implies \sum_{k=1}^\infty \text{trace}\big(A^{k}\big)\cdot z^{k}$ cannot converge absolutely in the unit disc

The trace is the sum of the EV. So if $A$ has EV $\lambda_i$, where we count each EV multiple times according to its algebraic multiplicity, then $A^k$ has as its EV $\lambda_i^k$. Now $f(x):=Tr(A^x)=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^x$ is a sum of exponentials, and as such only linear if it sums to 0.

Perhaps take into account repeated eigenvalues.

I would have liked more details for the last step. Why exactly can this sum not be equal to k for all natural k?
